# Setting a Corner Radius on a NavigationStack: Unresponsive Content View Areas in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, navigation, rounded-corners, ios17

I attempted to apply a `cornerRadius` to the `NavigationStack`, but as a result, the touch area became restricted to the initial view position. In simpler terms, if the slider is closed, you cannot open it by tapping it unless you touch the red area depicted in the image. (`ControllerView` is responsible for animation)

```
import SwiftUI

private struct ControllerView<Content: View>: View {
    private var content: Content
    @Binding var isOpen: Bool
    
    init(isOpen: Binding<Bool>, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self._isOpen = isOpen
        self.content = content()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            ZStack {
                Color.yellow.ignoresSafeArea()
                content
                    .cornerRadius(30) /// <- Here
                    .offset(x: isOpen ? 300 : 0)
            }
            .ignoresSafeArea()
        }
    }
}

private struct GreenView: View {
    @Binding var isOpen: Bool
    @Binding var navigation : [AnyHashable]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $navigation) {
            Color.green.ignoresSafeArea()
            .onTapGesture {
                print("GreenView tapped!")
                withAnimation { isOpen.toggle() }
            }
        }
    }
}


struct SwiftUIView9: View {
    @State private var isOpen = true
    
    var body: some View {
        ControllerView(isOpen: $isOpen) {
            GreenView(isOpen: $isOpen, navigation: .constant([]))
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    SwiftUIView9()
}
```

[image: Touchable Area]

Comment: Are you not offsetting the view by 300 to the right, making the touchable area how you showed in your image?

Comment: When the state is open, the view becomes offset. However, as it clear in the photo, in the closed state, the touchable area remains the same as in the open state. whole `GreenView` should be touchable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By trial and error, I found that if `isOpen` is initially `false`, i.e. initially `offset(0)`, then the tap area is correct.

We can exploit this by setting the offset initially to 0, and then immediately to `isOpen ? 300 : 0` when the view appears

```
@State var appeared = false

var correctOffset: CGFloat {
    if !appeared {
        return 0
    }
    return isOpen ? 300 : 0
}
```

Add an `onAppear` to set `appeared` to true:

```
content
    .cornerRadius(30)
    .offset(x: correctOffset)
    .onAppear {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            appeared = true
        }
    }
```

This incorrect touch area behaviour is happening with some other modifiers too, `clipped`, `colorInvert` etc. This might just be another quirk with `NavigationStack`.

Comment: I appreciate your reply and the provided link. Unfortunately, swapping the offset and corner radius does resolve the touch issue, BUT it results in the `GreenView`'s corners losing their roundness.

Comment: @Amirca I found another way. See the edit.

Comment: Awesome. Nice trick!