# Applying Corner Radius to NavigationStack: Restricted Interaction Areas

Tags: swift, button, swiftui, cornerradius, swiftui-navigationstack

I tried to set a `cornerRadius` for the `NavigationStack`, but it caused the touch area to be limited to the original view position. To put it simply, when the slider is closed, tapping it won't open it. The `ControllerView` manages the animation.
I could not use the [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77363610/8630152) for two changing view (Gray/Orange). The `cornerRadius` might **clip** or **mask** the content, leading to unresponsive touch areas. Are there any methods to prevent this issue?

```
import SwiftUI

private struct ControllerView<Content: View>: View {
    private var content: Content
    @Binding var isOpen: Bool
    
    
    init(isOpen: Binding<Bool>, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self._isOpen = isOpen
        self.content = content()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            content
                .cornerRadius(30)
                .offset(x: isOpen ? 300 : 0)
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}

private struct MenuView: View {
    @Binding var isGrayView: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Button {
                isGrayView.toggle()
                print("change View!")
            } label: {
                Text("change view")
            }
        }
    }
}

private struct OrangeView: View {
    @Binding var isOpen: Bool
    @Binding var navigation : [AnyHashable]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $navigation) {
            ZStack {
                Color.orange.ignoresSafeArea()
                Button {
                    isOpen.toggle()
                    print("orange tapped!")
                } label: {
                    Text("open/close")
                }
                .rotationEffect(.degrees(90))
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                
            }
        }
    }
}

private struct GrayView: View {
    @Binding var isOpen: Bool
    @Binding var navigation : [AnyHashable]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $navigation) {
            ZStack {
                Color.gray.ignoresSafeArea()
              
                Button {
                    isOpen.toggle()
                    print("Grey tapped!")
                } label: {
                    Text("open/close")
                }
                .rotationEffect(.degrees(90))
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            }
        }
    }
}


struct SwiftUIView14: View {
    @State private var isOpen = true
    @State private var isGrayView = true
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            MenuView(isGrayView: $isGrayView)
            
            ControllerView(isOpen: $isOpen) {
                if isGrayView {
                    GrayView(isOpen: $isOpen, navigation: .constant([]))
                } else {
                    OrangeView(isOpen: $isOpen, navigation: .constant([]))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


#Preview {
    SwiftUIView14()
}
```